# Need help on Java synchronization - Multhithreaded Envirnonment

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

I've below scenario where I'm thinking to apply synchronization, but I'm very new to multi thread programming, I need advice from experts whether this approach is right or not .

Scenario: We have coupon/promo code, we want allow only first 100 user to redeem the coupon/promo code, there is chance of getting millions of request as soon as we post the promo code in our web page but we want to restrict first 100 user to redeem.

Can I use synchronization concept here, which only one request at a time and reduce the count each time when user availed the promo code?

Or is there any other alternative approach of achieving this scenario?

Comment: Yes - when you write `synchronized(myObj) { ... }`, only **one thread** at a time can execute that block of code. Therefore, you should read and write a counter variable within that block of code, and take the necessary actions to approve/deny a request.

Comment: As for the social side of things, why not make it more fun? Instead of the first 100 users being successful, what about making the 1001th to 1100th user be successful? It could make the competition more interesting.